# VBA Macro Stops/Hangs Excel after about 4000 Iterations

Tags: excel, vba

I am posting this on behalf of someone else.  Hoping I learn something in the process.

One of my team members is working on an excel macro that loops through the rows in a spreadsheet that contains over 14,000 rows.  With each loop, it moves relevant data into a new tab within the workbook.  The loop completes successfully unless we use the LastRow variable, or if we tell it to go for more than 400-4500 rows, then it crashes or hangs without any useful error info.  The behavior does not change on different machines.  We are using Excel 2016 to run the macro.  I wanted to share the code with you to see if there is something that is causing it to hang (But why would it work fine for up to 4000 rows, and then quit beyond?  I suspect memory issues to be the cause...)

I am sorry if this is answered elsewhere, I am not experienced enough to recognize if certain suggestions apply to this particular code.

Here is the code:

```
Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
 End Function
Sub SortProductionIntoWorkcenters()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

LastRow = Worksheets("TL Production").Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FirstRow = 3
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
'The next line that says Cells(LastRow, 4)) is where I can change how may iterations the loop will process
Set rng = Worksheets("TL Production").Range(Cells(FirstRow, 4), Cells(LastRow, 4))
Dim SheetName As String
Dim r As Integer
r = 2

For Each cel In rng
    Worksheets("TL Production").Select
    If Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column) = "" Then
        Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column) = "EMPTY"
    End If

    SheetName = Worksheets("TL Production").Cells(cel.Row, 4).Value
    SheetName = Replace(SheetName, "/", " ")
    If Not SheetExists(SheetName) Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = SheetName
    End If
    Worksheets("TL Production").Rows(cel.Row).Cut

    Do While r > 0

        If IsEmpty(Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(r, 1)) Then
            Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(r).Insert shift:=xlDown
            r = 2
            Exit Do
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
Next cel
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
'MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
 ' MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: When I said " if we tell it to go for more than 400-4500 rows" I meant " if we tell it to go for more than 4000-4500 rows"

Comment: Can you go to the VBA Editor -> Tools (Top menu) -> Options -> General (Tab) -> Error Trapping (Section) -> Break on all Errors (checkbox) ?

Comment: `Do While r > 0` - r is always going to be greater than 0, you've established that and never reset it to anything less than 2 - if your `IsEmpty` never finds another match, that loop will never finish executing.

Comment: Get rid of `Do While Loop`. Instead declare a LastRow variable and find the first empty cell in column A and insert the copied content there. Otherwise for each cut and paste, do loop starts over again from row2 and tries to find the empty cell in column A. That is completely unnecessary for this task.

Comment: HI everyone, and thank you for your comments!  This may be coincidental, or a matter of luck...but I doubled my page file size and the macro finishes successfully.  However, I will review the suggestions here to simplify the code (I saw some great ideas)

Comment: Replace all your `Integer`s with `Long`. Use `Option Explicit` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but you would really benefit from simplifying your code. Eg:

```
For Each cel In rng
    Worksheets("TL Production").Select
    If cel = "" Then
        cel = "EMPTY"
    End If

    SheetName = cel
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not entirely sure what the real issue in your code is (could very well be memory related), I see a couple of things that can improve your code, as well as its performance. See the bottom of the post for my proposal of a revised version of your code.

---

```
For Each cel In rng
    Worksheets("TL Production").Select
    If Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column) = "" Then
        Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column) = "EMPTY"
    End If
```

Executing `.Select` every single loop slows down your code drastically, as each `.rows(r).Insert` seems to change to another sheet. So your code forces Excel to constantly switch Worksheets. Redrawing the screen is orders of magnitude slower than performing calculations or reading some values from the sheet.
This can be further mitigated by completely switching off screen updating:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ws.Select
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    ...
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

As mentioned by @PatrickHonorez, `Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column)` is a little bit overdoing it. It's a more complicated way of referencing `cel` - so why not use that directly? :) It also has the pitfall of not necessarily returning the correct cell, due to not being fully referenced. (`Cells` actually means `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells`, so if your Workbook/Sheet change due to whatever reason, your script suddenly runs into trouble.)

```
If cel.Value = "" Then
    cel.Value = "EMPTY"
End If
```

As mentioned in a comment by @dwirony, the `While r > 0` condition in the Do Loop isn't really doing anything. There is no path through your code that allows for  `r < 2`. Also, the way this loop is constructed is the major contributor to the macro's slow execution. (Several thousand rows in the original sheet means we enter this particular loop the equally often, and each time it has to count a little higher, due to the target sheets growing.)
I think this would be a good place to use a dictionary to store the number of the last row you inserted:

```
Do While r > 0
    DoEvents
    If IsEmpty(Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(r, 1)) Then
        Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(r).Insert shift:=xlDown
        dict(SheetName) = r
        Exit Do
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop
```

---

**Generally:**

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of any module. It will make your life easier. (Thus the compiler will force you to declare each and every variable you use. This makes your code more concise and eliminates potential typos, among other benefits.) You can also make this the standard in the VBA IDE's options.
- If the sheets modified by your macro contain formulas you can deactivate automatic recalculation (if not already set to manual) with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` - this will in some cases further reduce execution times. If you want to set it back to automatic afterwards, use `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`.
- Add a line `DoEvents` to each and every Do Loop you don't perfectly trust. This will allow you stop/pause the macro if it turns out to be an (almost) infinite loop.

---

My revised version, I tested it with about 6000 rows to be distributed to 3 different worksheets. It took about 2min to complete. Although rows with more data might take longer than my quick mock-up.

```
Sub SortProductionIntoWorkcenters()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
StartTime = Timer

Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set Ws = Worksheets("TL Production")    ' Set the reference to the starting sheet once and then use that
LastRow = Ws.Cells.SpecialCells(Type:=XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
FirstRow = 3
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
'The next line that says Cells(LastRow, 4)) is where I can change how may iterations the loop will process
Set rng = Ws.Range(Cells(FirstRow, 4), Cells(LastRow, 4))
Dim SheetName As String
Dim r As Long    ' Use Long datatype here to prevent integer overflow
r = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cel In rng.Cells   ' make explicit that we are iterating over all cells in range

    If cel.Value = "" Then
        cel.Value = "EMPTY"
    End If

    SheetName = Ws.Cells(cel.Row, 4).Value
    SheetName = Replace(SheetName, "/", " ")
    If Not SheetExists(SheetName) Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = SheetName
    End If
    Ws.Rows(cel.Row).Cut

    If Dict.Exists(SheetName) Then r = Dict(SheetName)
    Do
        DoEvents
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(r, 1)) Then
            Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(r).Insert shift:=xlDown
            Dict(SheetName) = r + 1     ' Add one, as the row r is not empty by defition
            Exit Do
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
'MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
 ' MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, @FunkTech, be aware that the cutting/inserting is most likely the reason the macro takes so long. I'm not sure there is a way around that. Also that might be related to the error you're getting. (But that's just a wild guess on my part.)

Comment: Thank you for this outstanding reply, I really do appreciate it.